# grep for string like xxx12345

Tags: sed, grep

I have 64 processes running that have the following string

```
pbs_mom -m -M 1234 -R 5678 -A foo12345 -c /var/spool/torque/mom_priv/login_config
```

I need to search and extract just foo12345

- always starts with 3 lowercase letters
- followed by 5 digits

Here is what I am trying but I am getting the entire line in return

```
ps aux |grep foo| grep 'foo[0-9]\+'
```

How can I strip off all text except foo12345.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `grep` is GNU `grep`, try the `-o` option:

```
ps aux |grep foo| grep -o 'foo[0-9]\+'
```

From man page of GNU `grep`:

> -o, --only-matching
>
> Prints only the matching part of the lines.

Based on your two requirements (3 lowercase letters followed by 5 digits), this should also work:

```
ps aux | grep -o '[a-z]\{3\}[0-9]\{5\}'
```

This is more efficient as it uses one pipe less.

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct would be to use sed like so:

```
ps aux | sed -n '/foo/s/.*\(foo[0-9]\{5\}\).*/\1/p'
```

However, since the data will be structured into a standard number of columns, you could instead use cut:

```
ps aux | grep foo | cut -d ' ' -f 8
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `grep` is not the GNU `grep`, you can always use Perl:

```
ps aux | perl -nle '/\s+([a-z]{3}[0-9]{5})\s+/ && print $1
```

or `awk` since your fields are already whitespace-separated:

```
ps aux | awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i ~ /[a-z]{3}[0-9]{5}/) print $i }'
```